# How to import a prepopulated SQLite DB in Document Folder in WinRT Tablet

Tags: sqlite, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have a pre-Populated SQite DB in Document Folder of WinRT Tablet.
How Can I import it into the App LocalFolder dynamically using code if this is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

To access documents library, you must have to upload app on company account. Individual account doesn't provide document access capability.

- Then open up **Package.appxmanifest**.
- Go to **Capabilities** tab and check mark the **Documents library**.
- Go to **Declaration** tab and **File Type Association** declaration.
- In properties section add any name in **Name** field and in Supported file type add database extension, in my case I was using **.sqlite**.
- Check out below given
  screenshot to not read the whole story :D

[image]

---

[image]

I would do using below given code.

```csharp
private async Task MoveOrCopyDatabaseAsync()
{
    var LocalFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var DbInDocument = await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.GetFileAsync("db.sqlite");

    //Moves the current file to the specified folder. You will get overloaded method here.
    await DbInDocument.MoveAsync(LocalFolder, "Desired_Name_Here.sqlite", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    //Creates a copy of the file in the specified folder. You will get overloaded method here.
    var DbLocal1 = await DbInDocument.CopyAsync(LocalFolder, "Desired_Name_Here.sqlite", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
}
```

Comment: What about enterprise App or LOB using license or license key? Thank u so much for this info and I never expected this requirement.

Comment: Can you confirm that App that not for listing in Appstore can not have access the DocumentLibrary capability to access files in Document folder?

Comment: I am not sure but it will work according to my thoughts. Please check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx#DocumentsLibrary and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/05/09/dealing-with-documents-how-not-to-use-the-documentslibrary-capability-in-windows-store-apps.aspx